# How can I use Gödel numbers to make a proof?

Tags: logic

As we know, any proposition can translate to Godel numbers, such as 
$$( \exists x)\space (x=sy)$$Its Godel numbers is $2^8 × 3 ^4 × 5^ {13} × 7^ 9 × 11^8 × 13^{13} × 17^ 5 × 19^ 7 × 23^ {17} × 29^ 9=a \space big \space number $

We also could get the character sequence "$( \exists x)\space (x=sy)$" through prime factorization of 243,000,000.

Such as$$243,000,000=2^6×3^5×5^6 $$
$$6\space\space\space\space\space 5\space\space\space\space\space 6 $$
$$\downarrow\space\space\downarrow\space\space\downarrow$$
$$0\space\space\space=\space\space\space 0 $$
So the Godel numbers of "$0=0$" is $243000000$

There are four axioms in Godel's PM system, here are two of them:
$$(p\lor p)\subset p$$
$$p\subset (p\lor q)$$
through these two axioms, we can prove "$(p\lor p)\subset(p\lor q)$" is a true theorem.

And these two axioms and a theorem all have a corresponding Godel numbers, can we prove this theorem is true through Godel numbers? If it works, how?

Many people think it is a question unrelated with Mathematica, but what I think is that if Gödel numbers could make a proof, then we can build an Association between characters and numbers in Mathematica, and add some rules, then we can prove propositions. But I’m not sure Gödel numbers can make a mathematical proof.

Comment: Probably this belongs on [math.se], not this site, which is a site for the computing software *Mathematica*.

Comment: A proof is also a succession of signs, so it can also be transcribed into a number in the exact same way. You can manipulate apply properties as operations on numbers.  For example if $\neg$ is coded by $123$, then property $\neg\neg P = P$ corresponds to a division by $2^{123}3^{123}$. Apart from that I voted to close for the reason above.

Comment: This question has nothing whatsoever to do with the *Mathematica* programming language and must be closed (moved to math...).

Answer (score 3):

You miss the point. Gödel numbers are just an encoding scheme for written text. You wouldn't ask "how would you prove a proposition by Gödel numbers" isn't realy any different from "how would you prove a proposition by text document".

The importance of Gödel numbering is that you can prove the rules of string manipulation can be expressed arithmetically, so that integer arithmetic is just as powerful.

(It's already known that the rules of arithmetic can be expressed by string manipulation; everyone how to do that in elementary school! The relevance to logic is that the subject of *syntax*, in particular *proof theory*, can also be expressed by string manipulation)

Comment: I think that there is a requirement that the representation has to be amenable to allowing the verification of an encoded proof being primitive recursive, so that there will be an equivalent expression for the correctness of an encoded proof in a simplistic logic like robinson arithmetic.  Probably beyond the scope of the question, but just saying it isn't an arbitrary encoding, or at least that the encoding dictates which proof systems the theorems using the encoding are applicable to.